# Google Sheets: SumIF(s) Summing by Week Day

Tags: google-sheets, sumifs

I have a table with dates in Col A and values in Col C.

I want to sum those values by week daylike this: `sumifs(C$2:C;A$2:A;weekday(A$2:A)=1)`, but even if I substitute `1` for any other value, the sum stays 0.

There are only positive, non-zero values in C. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
=sumproduct(weekday(A2:A) = 1;C2:C)
```

Answer (score 4):

Also:

```
=SUM(FILTER(C2:C,WEEKDAY(A2:A)=1))
```

and this:

```
=ArrayFormula(sumifs(C2:C,weekday(A2:A),1))
```

---

And this formula:

```
=QUERY(A:C,"select dayOfWeek(A), sum(C) group by dayOfWeek(A)")
```

would give all Weekdays and their sum:

[image]

Comment: At least for my version of Google Sheets, the commas don't work, must use semicolons. But actually, my question was: What is wrong with my formula, why does it not find the days? There must be some flawed thinking on my part and I want to correct it.